# Multitasking and app visibility on a Tizen app not working

Tags: javascript, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I've been trying to make the app adhere to Autorun Last App setting on SamsungTV, but this does not work. I've tried everything that was on StackOverflow and Samsung Developer Forum, but it doesn't work

Here's my **config.xml**

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:tizen="http://tizen.org/ns/widgets" viewmodes="fullscreen" id="https://company.website" version="1.2.4">
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
<tizen:metadata key="http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/multitasking.support" value="true"/>
<tizen:app-control>
    <tizen:src name="index.html" reload="disable"/>
    <tizen:operation name="http://samsung.com/appcontrol/operation/eden_resume"/>
</tizen:app-control>
<tizen:application required_version="2.3" package="12341234" id="12341234.companyAppName"/>
<author href="https://company.website" email="contact@company.website">CompanyAppName</author>
<content src="index.html"/>
<feature name="http://tizen.org/feature/screen.size.normal.1080.1920"/>
<icon src="400x400.png"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/network.public"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/appmanager.launch"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/display"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.info"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/tv.inputdevice"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/application.launch"/>
<tizen:profile name="tv-samsung"/>
<tizen:setting background-support="enable"/>
<tizen:setting screen-orientation="landscape"/>
<tizen:setting context-menu="enable"/>
<tizen:setting encryption="disable"/>
<tizen:setting install-location="auto"/>
<tizen:setting hwkey-event="enable"/>
<tizen:background-category value="media"/>
<tizen:video_splash_screen ready_when="video-finished">
    <tizen:vss_default background_color="#ffffff" image_border="0px stretch" video="intro.mp4" image="400x400.png" background_image="400x400.png"/>
</tizen:video_splash_screen>
<description/>
<name>CompanyAppName</name>
```

Did anyone encounter the same issue? I've been struggling to make this work. Tested this on 4 different TVs, none work whereas apps like Netflix or AppleTV have that functionality working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This demo can work well on the new Samsung TV even when it has been submitted since 2016.

Please check it out:

https://github.com/SamsungDForum/PlayerAVPlayMultitasking

Answer (score 0):

Autorun last app is same as multitasking.

For autorun last app support, there are 3 condition

1. App must support multitasking -> your config support it
2. Enable menu option (Autorun last app)
3. Product support multitaksing. Some of model didn't support it. leave your TV model. if multitasking support, your app will support autorun last app.

Netflix, Apple is not web app.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).